# How to identify rows per group before a certain value gap?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'd like to update a certain column in a table based on the difference in a another column value between neighboring rows in PostgreSQL.

Here is a test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   main INTEGER,
   sub_id INTEGER,
   value_t INTEGER);

INSERT INTO test (main, sub_id, value_t)
VALUES
    (1,1,8),
    (1,2,7),
    (1,3,3),
    (1,4,85),
    (1,5,40),
    (2,1,3),
    (2,2,1),
    (2,3,1),
    (2,4,8),
    (2,5,41);
```

My goal is to determine in each group `main` starting from `sub_id 1` which value in `diff` exceeds a certain threshold (e.g. <10 or >-10) by checking in ascending order by `sub_id`. Until the threshold is reached I would like to flag every passed row **AND** the one row where the condition is `FALSE` by filling column `newval` with a value e.g. `1`.

[image]

Should I use a loop or are there smarter solutions?

The task description in pseudocode:

```
FOR i in GROUP [PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id]:
    DO until diff > 10 OR diff <-10
        SET newval = 1 AND LEAD(newval) = 1
```

Comment: `After locating this value I want to overwrite all following numbers` <<-- use EXISTS(...)

Comment: Your code examples logic does not match the description and expected outcome above. Please clarify this.

Comment: Ok, done. Please have a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Basic `SELECT`

As fast as possible:

```sql
SELECT *, bool_and(diff BETWEEN -10 AND 10) OVER (PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id) AS flag
FROM (
   SELECT *, value_t - lag(value_t, 1, value_t) OVER (PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id) AS diff
   FROM   test
   ) sub;
```

Fine points

- Your thought model evolves around the window function [`lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). But its counterpart [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) is a bit more efficient for the purpose, since there is no off-by-one error when including the row before the big gap. ***Alternatively***, use `lead()` with inverted sort order (`ORDER BY sub_id DESC`).
- To avoid `NULL` for the first row in the partition, provide `value_t` as default as 3rd parameter, which makes the diff `0` instead of NULL. Both `lead()` and `lag()` have that capability.
- `diff BETWEEN -10 AND 10` is slightly faster than `@diff < 11` (clearer and more flexible, too). ([`@` being the "absolute value" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE), equivalent to the [`abs()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE).)
- [`bool_or()` or `bool_and()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) in the outer window function is probably cheapest to mark all rows up to the big gap.

#### Your `UPDATE`

> Until the threshold is reached I would like to flag every passed row AND the one row where the condition is `FALSE` by filling column `newval` with a value e.g. `1`.

Again, as fast as possible.

```sql
UPDATE test AS t
SET    newval = 1
FROM  (
   SELECT main, sub_id
        , bool_and(diff BETWEEN -10 AND 10) OVER (PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id) AS flag
   FROM (
      SELECT main, sub_id
           , value_t - lag(value_t, 1, value_t) OVER (PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id) AS diff
      FROM   test
      ) sub
   ) u
WHERE (t.main, t.sub_id) = (u.main, u.sub_id)
AND    u.flag;
```

Fine points

- Computing all values in a single query is typically substantially faster than a correlated subquery.
- The added WHERE condition `AND u.flag` makes sure we only update rows that actually need an update.
  If some of the rows may already have the right value in `newval`, add another clause to avoid those empty updates, too: `AND t.newval IS DISTINCT FROM 1`
  See:

  - [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)
- `SET newval = 1` assigns a constant (even though we could use the actually calculated value in this case), that's a bit cheaper.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c235ecea21af3420539ab0de4a81f66e)*

Answer (score 1):

Your question was hard to comprehend, the "value_t" column was irrelevant to the question, and you forgot to define the "diff" column in your SQL.

Anyhow, here's your solution:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT main, sub_id, value_t
       , abs(value_t
             - lead(value_t) OVER (PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id)) > 10 is_evil
  FROM test
)
SELECT main, sub_id, value_t
     , CASE max(is_evil::int)
            OVER (PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id
                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
       WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END newval
FROM data;
```

I'm using a CTE to prepare the data (computing whether a row is "evil"), and then the "max" window function is used to check if there were any "evil" rows before the current one, per partition.

Comment: `diff` is not in the original data. `abs(value_t - lead(value_t,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY main,sub_id))>10 AS is_evil`

Comment: @clamp Thanks for the clarification - updated the query according to what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS on an aggregating subquery:

---

```
UPDATE test u
SET value_t = NULL
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT main,sub_id
                , value_t , ABS(value_t - lag(value_t)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY main ORDER BY sub_id) ) AS absdiff
                FROM test
                ) x
        WHERE x.main = u.main
        AND x.sub_id <= u.sub_id
        AND x.absdiff >= 10
        )
        ;

SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY main, sub_id;
```

---

Result:

---

```
UPDATE 3
 main | sub_id | value_t 
------+--------+---------
    1 |      1 |       8
    1 |      2 |       7
    1 |      3 |       3
    1 |      4 |        
    1 |      5 |        
    2 |      1 |       3
    2 |      2 |       1
    2 |      3 |       1
    2 |      4 |       8
    2 |      5 |        
(10 rows)
```